# Why is this sample AppScript returning error: "Access Denied: DriveApp?"

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps-script

I received this error when attempting to run the sample Drive AppScript, even after authorizing the AppScript to access Drive. I have also tried hard-coding a folder ID and am receiving the same error.

The code is as follows:

```
function listFilesInFolder(id) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var file;
  var name;

  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    Logger.log(name);
  }
};
```

Comment: We recently (30/4/2019 4:28AM GMT)  started to receive this message "Access denied: DriveApp." on a folder.addFile() call. An app-script running as user that owns the folder. Cleaning up other files or changing the folder has not helped. It is as if the authorisation for the script to add files there has been forgotten. Problem still happening 2/5/2019 though we are working around it. I comment on here to see do other people sometimes see similar behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to execute the script, after authentication, without any problems. Most probably, the `DriveApp` isn't activated in the Admin Console for you or your domain.

The following issue might be of interest (read comment #5), if the problem persist: **[Issue 4006](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4006)**

Comment: I added info on what I see with addFile call here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761393#comment17

Answer (score 5):

In the Admin Console for you or your domain (admin.google.com) . section Drive - General settings - Enable "Allow users to install Google Drive Apps"

[image]