# AppScript that emails out a google spreadsheet as a PDF

Tags: email, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create an Google AppScript that emails out a google spreadsheet on a daily basis as a PDF.

Below is script I created based on example I found at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)

When I try to run script below I receive error "Access denied: DriveApp. (line 3, file "Code")"

What should I change to avoid receiving this error?

Or is there another way to have google spreadsheet emailed out on daily basis as PDF?

```
function emailSiteBody() {  
 // Send an email with attachment: a file from Google Drive (as a PDF).
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxxt9Qg5uTkTxxxxxxxxxDkRJVZ9OSYCWDEHGxxxxx');

 MailApp.sendEmail('first.last@domain.com', 'Attachment example', 'file attached.', {
     name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
     attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
 });
}
```

Comment: That code works fine for me. Check the account that is running the script has at least read access to the file you're using.

Comment: [See this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479205/why-is-this-sample-appscript-returning-error-access-denied-driveapp) for explanation why you get 'Access denied' error. Basically, you must enable "Allow users to install Google Drive Apps" option in Drive settings in Google Apps Admin Console.

Answer (score 0):

I've been informed by IT Admin

DriveApp API is blocked for security reasons. For now you can accomplish the same thing using the DocsList API but it is listed as experimental and as far as I can tell is an old deprecated API that will eventually be removed.

I changing DriveApp to DocsList and it is working now.  I'm not sure for how long.

Comment: no big surprises to be afraid of, keep an eye on [Apps-Script-Sunset](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset) to be informed