# Access Denied: DriveApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I created a file using DriveApp functions to copy multiple sheets.  The file works.  I have shared the file with someone else in a different domain, and when she runs the script she gets this error.

The specific error text is: Exception: Access denied: DriveApp

All files and folders have been shared with the user who is getting the error.

Does this mean that her domain admin needs to check to see if Drive SDK is enabled?  If it matters, here is the script (admittedly this script may be far from ideal as it is my first real foray into scripting in GS - this is a snippet of the code as it just repeats the same code for multiple sheets):

```
function CreateNewFiles() {

//get data from Master sheet
  
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CopyNames');
  

  var MT_CName = sheet.getRange(2,3).getValue(); //Master Template
  var IT_CName = sheet.getRange(3,3).getValue(); //IT Template
  var RG_CName = sheet.getRange(4,3).getValue(); //RG Template
  var DC_CName = sheet.getRange(5,3).getValue(); //DC Template
  var H_CName = sheet.getRange(6,3).getValue(); //H Template

  

   var MT_source_file = DriveApp.getFileById('1bymh-X_3luxh7PVhAltvGtUM-HhYIuyBQbOjSA_5JfY');
   var MT_source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('14KySop_wFAbJHv2Jj8RRseIp8utDT_Md');
   var MT_destinationfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1Q2_HB-5ZWexy7-xbJ1jyIqmUwsnm0CEk');
   var MT_source_url = MT_source_file.getUrl();
   var MT_Source_Id = MT_source_file.getId();

   //create new file
    var MT_newFileName = MT_source_file.makeCopy(MT_CName,MT_destinationfolder);
    
    

    MT_newFileName.moveTo(MT_destinationfolder);

    var MT_newId = MT_newFileName.getId();
    var MT_newUrl = MT_newFileName.getUrl();

    var MT_destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(MT_newId);
    var MTIT_destinationSheet = MT_destination.getSheetByName("IT Sales");
    var MTRG_destinationSheet = MT_destination.getSheetByName("RG Sales");
    var MTDC_destinationSheet = MT_destination.getSheetByName("DC Sales");
    var H_destinationSheet = MT_destination.getSheetByName("H Sales");
    var MTIT_destinationCell = MTIT_destinationSheet.getRange("A1");
    var MTRG_destinationCell = MTRG_destinationSheet.getRange("A1");
    var MTDC_destinationCell = MTDC_destinationSheet.getRange("A1");
    var H_destinationCell = H_destinationSheet.getRange("A1");

    //Copy H Sales
  
  
  //create new IT file
  

  

   var IT_source_file = DriveApp.getFileById('1cUgmroY4wwEDDU2fP9Sm_77vXO2OAENCIN8t4KIAzco');
   var IT_source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('14KySop_wFAbJHv2Jj8RRseIp8utDT_Md');
   var IT_destinationfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1FljFT8IQTq4MlJFShobw1RodcEHMVTQt');
   var IT_Source_Id = IT_source_file.getId();


   
    var IT_newFileName = IT_source_file.makeCopy(IT_CName,IT_destinationfolder);
    
    var IT_newId = IT_newFileName.getId();
    var IT_newUrl = IT_newFileName.getUrl();
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please replace your code by a [mcve] including the textual error message.

Comment: Also confirm that the files and folders referred by your script are shared with the people that are getting the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this sample AppScript returning error: "Access Denied: DriveApp?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479205/why-is-this-sample-appscript-returning-error-access-denied-driveapp)

Comment: Most probably, that someone's `DriveApp` isn't activated in its domain.

Comment: Hi @MWL, if you were able to confirm the issue, please do notify us here. Thanks.

Comment: I confirmed the setup with the client, and they are still having the issue.