# How to make a shortcut to a FILE in a specific Folder in Appscript via DriveApp

Tags: google-apps-script

In the beginning i used `todayfolder.createShortcut(id)`

It worked for a few times and then it straight up started giving me this error :

```js
Exception: Access denied: DriveApp.
```

and there was this link , that points to where the error was made , when I click that, the cursor is put right before `createShortcut(id)`

The thing is , its running in a loop and I mean to make shortcuts of many files , but it throws an error for the first file so it stops there. Which means it shouldn't make any shortcuts right ? **But it does! It only makes the first shortcut.**

the `todayfolder` is defined so :

```js
var todayfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(<folder id>)
```

From then, I have searched for alternative methods to make shortcuts and these are the ones I have tried

```js
      var shortcut = todayfolder.createShortcut(id)
      // error : Exception: Access denied: DriveApp.

      //alternate methods to create shortcut , from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62047554/how-to-create-a-shortcut-in-google-drive-apps-script-instead-of-multiple-parents
        // Drive.Files.insert({
        //   shortcutDetails: {targetId: id},
        //   parents: [{id: todayfolderId}],
        //   title: file.getName(),
        //   mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut"
        //   });
        // error 2 : GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: File not found

      // another attempt at making a shortcut 
      // todayfolder.createFile(file.getBlob())
      // errror : Exception: File <file name>  exceeds the maximum file size. 
      // it tries to copy the files , which i dont want 

      //another attempt : THIS WORKS , but its un playable , it just shows download , ie if its a video, i expect the shortcut of the video to be playable then and there with a double click , but this doesnt do that.  
      // todayfolder.createFile(file.getName(),{
      //     shortcutDetails: {targetId: id},
      //     parents: [{id: todayfolderId}],
      //     title: file.getName(),
      //     mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut",
      //     })
```

This is my appscript.json

```js
{
  "oauthScopes" : [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
  ],
  "timeZone": "StackOverflow/Confused",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Drive",
        "version": "v2",
        "serviceId": "drive"
      }
    ]
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "MYSELF",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Where is the createShortcut going wrong ? Or how do i make a shortcut without it ?

Comment: Check your domain settings maybe Drive has been disabled? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479205/

Comment: Also https://issuetracker.google.com/36761393

Comment: @RafaGuillermo unfortunately i do not have access to my domain settings ( but it works for one shortcut so it should probably have have drive enabled )

Comment: I suggest perhaps spacing out your requests with a sleep, try implementing some form of exponential backoff to see if this helps?